# Dynamic report builder using jstree and datatable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datatables, jstree-dnd

I want to build a report builder, where user can drag and drop columns from jstree to the boostrap table , column should be added to the table dragged from jstree , where inbetween i need do some ajax in order to retrieve the data from the jstree dragged column. Please suggest me , how to proceed, i am struct and google alot. Please suggest some overview of solution.

Comment: Please remember that SO is not code writing service, you need to show what you've tried so far, please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi, I am not asking for code, just guide lines of couple libraries to start with...

Comment: Questions asking to recommend a library is off-topic on StackOverflow, see [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), most likely your question will be closed.